# How to save model manipulation of *ngFor with pipes? - "#item of (result = (items | orderAsc))" doesn't work in A2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

So I populate a table with *ngFor and use pipes to filter and order the given items array. This works perfectly and the table rows are created as expected. But I also wan't to use the result of the pipes in my component hosting the table. How can this be achieved with angular2?

my current html:

```
<tr *ngFor="#item of items | orderAsc">{{item.name}}</tr>
```

the old angularJS way of saving the result:

```
<tr *ngFor="#item of (result = (items | orderAsc))">{{item.name}}</tr>
```

where "result" could be used in the corresponding controller.

What is the angular2 way of achieving this? I'd like to keep the filtering in the html template and not move it into the component.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the old way isn't supported.

I have a workaround for this but I don't know if it's a clean way to do ;-)

You could implement a custom pipe (the `dump` one in the following sample) you put at the end of your pipe chain to save the filtered value into the component

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe {
  (...)
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class FilterPipe {
  (...)
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'dump'
})
export class DumpPipe {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) app:AppComponent) {
    this.app = app;
  }

  transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {
    this.app.save(array);
    return array;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
    <div>
      <span *ngFor="#l of (list | filter | sort)">{{l}}</span>
    </div>
  `,
  pipes: [ FilterPipe, SortPipe, DumpFilter ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [ 'n', 'g', 'a', 'u', 'r', 'l' ];
  }

  save(array) {
    console.log('save array = '+array);
  }
}
```

When the expression is evaluated, the `dump` pipe calls the `save` method of the component with the filtered and sorted value.

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/xv4BTq7aCyKJSKcA9qB9?p=preview

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Doesn't look like a clean way, but something that works. I wanted to reuse the DumpPipe, so I used your approach and made it kind of configureable, by makeing use of the args of the pipe where a component can place the variable it want to be filled with the value of the DumpPipe:

HtmlTemplate: "dump: result"
Component: "result: any = {}"
DumpPipe: "let [result] = args; result['pipeResult'] = value"

Comment: Also thanks :-) Couldn't edit the comment above anymore.

Comment: Yes, agreed with you that it's not a very clean solution... But I don't see any other solution... Pleased to have helped you. Perhaps someone else will provide a better solution... Feel free to upvote my answer ;-)

Comment: Need to get some rep in order to be able to upvote, sorry ;-)

Comment: I understand well ;-) No worries!

Comment: Great solution. I see the post dates back to a beta version of Angular2: is there a simpler way to achieve the save of the pipe output ? remark : the use of the 'dump' pipe is missing in the template, no ?  list | filter | sort | dump

Comment: Love it, thanks for documenting your solution.  While https://stackoverflow.com/a/35127331/3232832 would work for many cases, I needed an 'interim' pipe to dump out results that was not at the end of the pipe chain.

Answer (score 0):

According [the official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) it should be:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items | orderAsc as result">{{item.name}} ( {{result.length}} )</tr>
```