# Angular How to find the count of items in an ngFor after the pipes have been applied before slice pipe

Tags: angular, pipe

Basically i am trying to get piped result's length before slice pipe is applied, 
code sample is -

[image]

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let sub of subs | Filter1: { Name1: name1}:true |
  Filter2: { Name2: name2}:true | searchFilter: { mobilenumber: searchText }: false |
  slice: startIndex:endIndex  as result;let i=index;">
    // table code
</ng-container>
```

is it possible to get length before the data get sliced.I tried to get it "as result" in the ng-container but i am getting "Template parse errors:" does anybody have solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: it seems like you need to [edit] your question and make sure your code and the **full** error message are properly included here.

Comment: added issue in image

Comment: you mean you want `subs` length before slice or what ?

Comment: Check your angular version. The code is working for Angular 4+. Which version of angular are you using? Checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127257/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-filtered-piped-set-in-angular2 for more details

Comment: yes i want subs length before slice.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I achieve this by using a function and using filter in `.ts`

Search input field in html file.

```
<div class="is-empty">
                <input class="effect-1 form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Search" type="text"
                       [(ngModel)]="salesByCountryReportObj.search" (ngModelChange)="getFilteredResults()">
                <span class="focus-border"></span>
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
              </div>
```

and then in `.ts` file

```
import {SearchFilterPipe} from "@app/shared/pipes/search-filter.pipe";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sales-by-country',
  templateUrl: './sales-by-country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sales-by-country.component.scss'],
  providers: [ SearchFilterPipe ]
})

export class SalesByCountryComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private searchFilter: SearchFilterPipe){}

getFilteredResults() {
let filteredArray = this.searchFilter.transform(this.subs, this.salesByCountryReportObj.search);
console.log(filteredArray.length);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days back what I did was create another div:

```
<div #count>{{(subs | filter:searchText).length}}</div>
<ng-container *ngFor="let sub of subs | Filter1: { Name1: name1}:true |
  Filter2: { Name2: name2}:true | searchFilter: { mobilenumber: searchText }: false |
  slice: startIndex:endIndex  as result;let i=index;">
    // table code
</ng-container>
```

In the .ts file:

```
@ViewChild('count') count: any;
console.log(+(this.count.nativeElement.innerText));
```

This might look like a hack, and there can be a better solution.